How to create a Pydantic type without a keyword argument?
I'm working with a number of data types and often pass data_type as an argument to my functions/methods/classes. For type hinting, I've considered doing
from typing import Literal

data_type: Literal["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"]

But this seems brittle. If I need to add a new data type, I need to update the type hints everywhere and this isn't DRY. Is this even an issue?
So, I created a DataType type in a very hacky way:
VALID_DATA_TYPES = {"type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"}
DataType = Literal[tuple(VALID_DATA_TYPES)]

I'm considering switching to Pydantic to get param validation and am doing it properly.
But I don't like how you have to pass an argument name (value in this case) in Pydantic
from pydantic import BaseModel

class DataType(BaseModel):
    value: Literal["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"]
    
DataType(value="type1") # all good
DataType(value="error") # ValidationError

Is it possible to use a Pydantic model like so?
DataType("type1") # all good
DataType("error") # ValidationError

I find it odd that this functionality doesn't exist out of the box... perhaps I am just doing something that isn't common/necessary?
Note: I do not want to use an Enum. I want to explore other options.

Is this question about type checking or Pydantic?

Are you trying to create an enum? https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

As I understand the post, the question is: "Can I create a Pydantic model using positional arguments instead of keyword arguments?"

@InSync check my comment above and see if it makes sense, please!

@MatBailie check my comment above and see if it makes sense, please!

@enzo That would be Y. I'm interested in X. As in, the XY problem.

@MatBailie I like passing around strings to my functions/methods so am resisting using an enum

@InSync about using pydantic to implement a type?

@enzo yes that is part of the question

Does this answer your question? How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?

casually, there is no need to try and shoehorn strong typing into Python, just directly use a string or enum and check in your function if it's right if you know it has to be a member of some set

You think something should be native, but you prefer string literals, so you don't want to use that standard native behaviour? Why?

@MatBailie I could be overthinking. But I thought automatically validating the input could be better than having a _validate_input method I call repeatedly. Open to different ideas (hence the question).

@ti7 no, I don't want to use an enum. They seem so clunky. Maybe it's because I do ML but I much prefer strings.

@ti7 fair point about not needing strong typing. I'm productionising a system and want to make it more robust and thought adding stronger typing would help.

Use pydantic dataclasses. They provide validation without needing keyword arguments.
from typing import Literal
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class DataType:
    value: Literal["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"]

dt = DataType('type2') # ok

dt = DataType('oopsy') # ValidationError


Aha! This is it!

Is that what you need?
from pydantic import BaseModel, RootModel, model_validator
from pydantic.json_schema import SkipJsonSchema

class DataType(BaseModel):
    value: Literal["type1", "type2", "type3", "type4"]

    def __init__(self, *args):
        field_names = self.model_fields.keys()
        kwargs = dict(zip(field_names, args))
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
 
DataType("type1") # all good
DataType("error") # ValidationError


